# Angular 6 - In MCQ, [(ngModel)] show the good answer

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngmodel

I'm working on a MCQ in Angular 6. I have a problem with my checkboxs which show the good answer straight away because of this line: [(ngModel)]="answer.good". But the problem is that without this line i can't determine if the answers are good or bad.

**answer.component.html :**

```
<div class="" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
    <div class="answer">
        <label class="container"> 

            <input type="checkbox" 
                [(ngModel)]="answer.good" />
            {{answer.text}}
            <span class="checkmark"></span>

        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does someone has a solution to keep the record of the answers of the user but hide the good answer in the same time ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I don't want ngModel to show the good answer. But i need to keep track if the answer chosen by the user is good or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the input as

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="answer.good" (ngModelChange)="checkGood($event)" />
```

and in the ts

```
checkGood(good){
   if(good){
   // do what you want with good
   }
}
```